# Response body not showing when using JPA Query

Tags: spring, api, spring-mvc, jpa, swagger

I'm trying to display an specific entity data using jpa query methods to find them by their "Nome" param and order in ascending and descending order.

I'm using the following query methods :

```
public List<Cliente> findByNomeOrderByNomeAsc(String nome);
public List<Cliente> findByNomeOrderByNomeDesc(String nome);
```

My controllers code is :

```
@ApiImplicitParam(name = "Authorization", value = "Bearer Token", required = true,
        allowEmptyValue = false, paramType = "header", example = "Bearer access_token")
@ApiOperation("Listar todos os clientes por nome em ordem crescente")
@GetMapping("/nome/asc/{nome}")
public List<Cliente> listarPorNomeOrdemCrescente(@PathVariable String nome) {
    return clienteRepository.findByNomeOrderByNomeAsc(nome);
}


@ApiImplicitParam(name = "Authorization", value = "Bearer Token", required = true,
        allowEmptyValue = false, paramType = "header", example = "Bearer access_token")
@ApiOperation("Listar todos os clientes por nome em ordem decrescente")
@GetMapping("/nome/desc/{nome}")
public List<Cliente> listarPorNomeOrdemDecrescente(@PathVariable String nome) {
    return clienteRepository.findByNomeOrderByNomeDesc(nome);
}
```

For some reason, I'm getting an empty vector as response, meaning that the list is empty.

[image: Screenshot]

Cliente entity :

```
@Entity
@ApiModel(value = "Cliente", description = "Representa um cliente")
@Table(name = "cliente")
public class Cliente {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String nome;

    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    private String senha;

    @NotNull
    private String documento;

    @NotNull
    private Date dataCadastro;

    //getters and setters
    }
```

Would appreciate if someone could help me with this one. Thank you.

Comment: Entity `Cliente` and rows in db that should appear?

Comment: @pirho I've edited the question just now to include the entity Cliente! See if that may help.

Comment: What is in the database? Can you show the rows that should appear?

Comment: What's the code of `clienteRepository.findByNomeOrderByNomeAsc()` and `.findByNomeOrderByNomeDesc()`?

Comment: @pirho The columns are the entity parameters and the rows are its values, right? By that sense, the rows are just some generic mock data.

Comment: @Helen the code is just that, it's a JPA query, not sure how it works